# How can I delete child nodes of selected node in telerik kendo treeview

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

[image]

I want to remove all child of selected node like highlighted div in image.

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet:

```
var tv = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");

$(tv.element).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each((i, item) =>
{
      $(item).closest("li").find("ul li").each((i, removeItem) => tv.remove(removeItem));
});
```

It finds all checked checkboxes and remove its children.

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IveSo)